# Effective way to tell when binary data changes

Tags: r

I have one column in a data frame that is binary data made of 1s and 2s.

```r
dat<-data.frame(a = rep(c(1,2,1), c(3,10,6)),b=rnorm(19))
```

What is the most efficient way to get the index of the points where the binary data shifts from 1 to 2 and save them to a new data frame `changes` so that it will look like this:

```r
> changes
3
13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare the adjacent elements by removing the first and last elements of the column 'a', get the position with `which`

```
with(dat, which(a[-1] != a[-length(a)]))
#[1]  3 13
```

---

Or using `diff` (if the column is numeric)

```
with(dat, which(diff(a)!= 0))
#[1]  3 13
```

---

Or another option with `rle`

```
head(cumsum(rle(dat$a)$lengths), -1)
#[1]  3 13
```